# Multiple Logstash instances causing duplication of lines

Tags: redis, duplicates, jruby, logstash

We're receiving logs using Logstash with the following configuration:

```
input {
  udp {
    type => "logs"
    port => 12203
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    type => "tracker"
     pattern => '%{GREEDYDATA:message}'
  }
  date {
    type => "tracker"
    match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
  }
}

output{
    tcp{
         type => "logs"
         host => "host"
         port => 12203
    }
}
```

We're then picking the logs up on the machine `"host"` with the following settings:

```
input {
      tcp {
                      type => "logs"
                      port => 12203
                        }
}


output {
    pipe {
        command => "python /usr/lib/piperedis.py"
    }
}
```

From here, we're doing parsing of the lines and putting them into a Redis database. However, we've discovered an interesting problem.

Logstash 'wraps' the log message in a JSON style package i.e.:

```
{\"@source\":\"source/\",\"@tags\":[],\"@fields\":{\"timestamp\":[\"2013-09-16 15:50:47,440\"],\"thread\":[\"ajp-8009-7\"],\"level\":[\"INFO\"],\"classname\":[\"classname\"],\"message\":[\"message"\]}}
```

We then, on receiving it and passing it on on the next machine, take that as the message and put it in another wrapper! We're only interested in the actual log message and none of the other stuff (source path, source, tags, fields, timestamp e.t.c.)

Is there a way we can use filters or something to do this? We've looked through the documentation but can't find any way to just pass the raw log lines between instances of Logstash.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logstash documentation is wrong - it indicates that the default "codec" is [plain](http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.1/outputs/pipe#codecs) but in fact it doesn't use a codec - it uses an output [format](https://github.com/logstash/logstash/blob/v1.2.1/lib/logstash/outputs/pipe.rb#L43).

To get a simpler output, change your output to something like

```
output {
    pipe {
        command => "python /usr/lib/piperedis.py"
        message_format =>  "%{message}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just extract those messages from stdout?

```
line = sys.stdin.readline()
line_json = json.loads(line)
line_json['message'] # will be your @message
```